# Рекурсивная функция перебора всех возможных вариаций углов у ломаной

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-c++, рекурсия

Столкнулся с проблемой: Имеется ломанная линия, состоящая из отрезков различной длины и углов, на которые эти отрезки могут свободно двигаться. В поставленной мне задаче, необходимо сделать некие расчеты для каждой возможной точки окончания данной ломаной. Проблема состоит в том, что не могу логически продумать, как можно написать рекурсивную функцию, которая для n соединений отрезков проходила бы по всем возможным вариациям поворота данных углов.

Приведу пример:
Имеется 4 отрезка ломанной, попарно соединённые тремя "шарнирными соединениями", которые максимум могут поворачиваться на thetta1_ = 15, thetta2_ = 60, thetta3 = 45 градусов. Мне нужно перебрать все возможные состояния данных трёх углов (на самом деле не все, скорее всего буду каждый из углов делить на 6, или брать какое-то фиксированное и перебирать состояния каждого угла на полученное значение, дабы не нагружать через чур долго проц при больших значениях n ), то есть, например, ( 0, 0, 5 ), ( 0, 0, 10 ), ( 0, 0, 15), ( 0, 5, 0 ), ( 0, 5, 5 ) и т.д.

Иначе говоря, чтобы результат работы подобной функции для n = 3, был по логике похож на

```
for (float angl1_ = 0; angl1_ <= thetta1_; angl1_ += 15)
{
    for (float angl2_ = 0; angl2_ <= thetta2_; angl2_ += 15)
    {
        for (float angl3_ = 0; angl3_ <= thetta3_; angl3_ += 15)
        {
            DoSomething( angl1_, angl2_, angl3_ );
        }
    }
}
```

Надеюсь, что адекватно смог изложить суть проблемы.

Comment: У вас тут обычный граф с обходом в ширину и рекурсивный алгоритм соответствующий

Comment: А рекурсия - обязательное условие? Почему не взять, например, вектор/массив длиной `n` и не смоделировать постепенное итеративное увеличение с переносом?...

Comment: а какая конечеая цель? по описанию чем то напоминает inverse kinematic

Comment: @stranger-in-the-q, почти. Пытаюсь отрисовать пространство достижимых точек манипулятора для заданных длин сегментов, точки начала и углов, на которые сочленения способны поворачиваться. Иначе говоря, прямая кинематическая задача.